# Python sudoku solver blocks

Tags: python, block, sudoku, solver

I have a problem with my sudoku solver.
I was able to check vertical and horizontal but now i will check the blocks. 
This is the code i have now for checking the blocks

```
def print_sudoku(array):
    for i in range(0,3):
        print()
        for j in range(0,3):
            print(array[i][j][0],end=' ')
def controleren(array):
    for i in range(0,8):
        for j in range(0,8):
            if distance[i][j][1] + distance[i][j][2]+ distance[i][j][3]+ distance[i][j][4]+ distance[i][j][5]+ distance[i][j][6]+ distance[i][j][7]+ distance[i][j][8]+ distance[i][j][9] == 1:
                if distance[i][j][k] == 1:
                    distance[i][j][k] = k

def main():
    pass
import pprint
distance = [[[0 for k in range(10)] for j in range(3)] for i in range(3)]

distance[0][0][0] = '*'
distance[0][1][0] = 2
distance[0][2][0] = 3
distance[1][0][0] = 4
distance[1][1][0] = 5
distance[1][2][0] = 6
distance[2][0][0] = 7
distance[2][1][0] = 8
distance[2][2][0] = 9

print_sudoku(distance)
```

Here i'm giving every possibility the value 1

```
for i in range(0,3):
    for j in range(0,3):
        if distance[i][j][0] == '*':
            for k in range(1,10):
                distance[i][j][k] = 1
```

This is the important part. The while loop is infinite distance[0][0][0] remains equal to * instead of get the value of 1 that is the only number what is missing in the block. What is happening is: that every value that is already standing in one of the othor distance[][][] is set to 0

```
while distance[0][0][0] == '*':
    for i in range(0,3):
        for j in range(0,3):
            if distance[i][j][0] != '*':
                k = distance[i][j][0]
                for i in range(0,3):
                    for j in range(0,3):
                        distance[i][j][k] = 0
```

In this part the code looks for the missing number so is there one possibilty, one number with the value 1 because that number is the missing number.

```
    for i in range(0,3):
        for j in range(0,3):
            if distance[i][j][1] + distance[i][j][2]+ distance[i][j][3]+ distance[i][j][4]+ distance[i][j][5]+ distance[i][j][6]+ distance[i][j][7]+ distance[i][j][8]+ distance[i][j][9] == 1:
                for k in range(1,10):
                    if distance[i][j][k] == 1:
                        distance[i][j][0] = k

print('')
print_sudoku(distance)
```

I hope you do understand it, probably not (i find it hard to explain what i'm doing) so just say it if something is not clear.

Rudy

Comment: I know it's not your main problem but you don't need 0 as first argument in range. range(3) is sufficient.

Comment: Yea you're right but it is just a habbit i think :)

Comment: self promotion: I wrote a sudoku solver in Excel VBA. The code is at https://github.com/wkschwartz/xlSudoku

Comment: Are you aware that in your infinite while loop, there are two `i`s and `j`s? If it's not on purpose thing, try to rename them as something else like n-m.

Comment: In your while loop, you have nested for loops that use the same iteration variable.  That will cause problems.

Comment: The i and j stands for the place i wants to put the number. So if number 2 is standing in distance[0][1][0] I want al the others with k set to 0 instead of 1 so that is why there are those other two for loops they set al distance[i][j][2] = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while distance[0][0][0] == '*':
    for i in range(0,3):
        for j in range(0,3):
            if distance[i][j][0] != '*':
                k = distance[i][j][0]
                for i in range(0,3):
                    for j in range(0,3):
                        distance[i][j][k] = 0
```

In here there are two `i`s and `j`s. I think this is the part causing the problem. Try to rename them because it affects the output.

So the bottom part should look like this.

```
 k = distance[i][j][0]
 for m in range(0,3):
     for n in range(0,3):
         distance[m][n][k] = 0
```

This is your code.

```
distance = [[[0 for k in range(10)] for j in range(3)] for i in range(3)]

distance[0][0][0] = '*'
distance[0][1][0] = 2
distance[0][2][0] = 3
distance[1][0][0] = 4
distance[1][1][0] = 5
distance[1][2][0] = 6
distance[2][0][0] = 7
distance[2][1][0] = 8
distance[2][2][0] = 9

for i in range(0,3):
    for j in range(0,3):
        if distance[i][j][0] == '*':
            for k in range(1,10):
                distance[i][j][k] = 1

if distance[0][0][0] == '*':
    for i in range(0,3):
        for j in range(0,3):
            if distance[i][j][0] != '*':
                k = distance[i][j][0]
                for i in range(0,3):
                    for j in range(0,3):
                        distance[i][j][k] = 0
print (distance)
```

When there are same iteration variables:

```
>>>[[['*', 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], ... ]
```

After you rename them:

```
>>>[[['*', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ...]
```

I changed `while` to `if` to see changes in `distance`.

Comment: So the only thing I have to do is change the second two for loops to other number like n and m and distance[i][j][k] to distance[n][m][k]?

Comment: Yeap. I forgot to add them. Editing the answer.

Comment: You're right it works fine!! Thank you! but for the other blocks I can just variate the ranges?